# HTML5 input validate at least 1 letter and 1 number in the field

Tags: html, forms, validation

I'm stuck with HTML5 form validation. I need to meet these parameters:

- at least 1 number
- at least 1 letter (any case)

How can I do this using a pattern attribute? For example:

```
<input type="password" pattern="myPattern" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*"
```

Please try googling; many examples of how to use `pattern` can be seen here:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp